# Extracting the Linear Discriminant Equation

Tags: r, statistics

So I have this data and I would like to extract the coefficients from the equation it produces. That way I would be able to plug in a new data point and see where it would be placed.

```
library(MASS)
Iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
               Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))
train <- sample(1:150, 75)
table(Iris$Sp[train])
## your answer may differ
##  c  s  v
## 22 23 30
z <- lda(Sp ~ ., Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)
```

I know I can get this:

```
> z
Call:
lda(Sp ~ ., data = Iris, prior = c(1, 1, 1)/3, subset = train)

Prior probabilities of groups:
    c         s         v 
0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 

Group means:
  Sepal.L. Sepal.W. Petal.L.  Petal.W.
c 5.969231 2.753846 4.311538 1.3384615
s 5.075000 3.541667 1.500000 0.2583333
v 6.700000 2.936000 5.552000 1.9880000

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
                LD1        LD2
Sepal.L. -0.5458866  0.5215937
Sepal.W. -1.5312824  1.7891248
Petal.L.  1.8087255 -1.2637188
Petal.W.  2.8620894  3.2868849

Proportion of trace:
   LD1    LD2 
0.9893 0.0107
```

but is there a way to get just the equation so I would not have to calculate the new observation by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turning this into an answer. You need `predict()`, the `predict.lda` method in the MASS package has your exact example in its help page:

```
tr <- sample(1:50, 25)
train <- rbind(iris3[tr,,1], iris3[tr,,2], iris3[tr,,3])
test <- rbind(iris3[-tr,,1], iris3[-tr,,2], iris3[-tr,,3])
cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))
z <- lda(train, cl)
predict(z, test)$class
```

Answer (score 1):

The default method is "plug-in" so this is the code from `MASS:::predict.lda`. `object` is the fit-object and `x` comes from the `newdata` argument converted to a matrix:

```
# snipped preamble and error checking
means <- colSums(prior * object$means)
scaling <- object$scaling
x <- scale(x, center = means, scale = FALSE) %*% scaling
dm <- scale(object$means, center = means, scale = FALSE) %*% 
    scaling
method <- match.arg(method)
dimen <- if (missing(dimen)) 
    length(object$svd)
else min(dimen, length(object$svd))
N <- object$N
if (method == "plug-in") {
    dm <- dm[, 1L:dimen, drop = FALSE]
    dist <- matrix(0.5 * rowSums(dm^2) - log(prior), nrow(x), 
        length(prior), byrow = TRUE) - x[, 1L:dimen, drop = FALSE] %*% 
        t(dm)
    dist <- exp(-(dist - apply(dist, 1L, min, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
@ snipped two other methods

}
posterior <- dist/drop(dist %*% rep(1, ng))
```

This mostly put in to demonstrate why Gregor's answer is the most sensible approach. Trying to pull out an "equation" seems unfruitful. (I can remember using the results of linear regression to do such an exercise in my first year-regression class in grad school.)